# Array definition

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I would like to define an array that will contain the indices from two arrays that meet specific criteria:

Is this valid?

```
f = { [i] | u[i]>0 & u[i]<1 & x[i]>x_s & x[i]
```

In particular, I have two arrays; x[1..n] and u[1..n] and I would like to create an array of indices given some conditions x values of x and u. so for example if x[0] > a and x [0] is < b and u[0] is > c and u[0] > d , I will add the value 0 to this new array.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, kindly explain in more detail.

Comment: Thanks.I would like to describe an algorithm where I have two arrays; x[1..n] and u[1..n] and I would like to create an array of indices given some conditions x values of x and u. so for example if x[0] > a and x [0] is < b  and u[0] is > c and u[0] > d , I will add the value 0 to this new array.

Comment: @CarmelGafa please edit your question instead of using comments to clarify.

Comment: thanks, still a newbie at this!

Comment: What is your question? Do you know for-loops and simple conditional operators (if)?

Comment: Just want to ensure that this is the formal way of writing it. I have some experience with loops and conditions

Answer (score 0):

Defining an array using the mathematical notation will be quite cumbersome. If you want to define the **set** meeting you desired conditions you (almost) got it right:

```
{ i | x[i] > a & x[i] < b & u[i] > c & u[i] < d}
```

(the '&' should be substituted with mathematical ands (upside-down 'v'))

Comment: Perfect! just what I needed to know! Thank you so much @Saibot